# How to update style of a React element with className

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, getelementsbyclassname

So I'm using Ant Design UI library with my create react app which is making it difficult for me to edit the style of more complicated Ant Design components. Like the progress bar is by default blue:

[image]

I want to make it another color and when I look at HTML in the Chrome console I see:

[image]

The `className` for that element is `ant-progress-bg`. Is there any way I can write some code in my React component and update the style to be from `style={width: "12.5%, height: 8}` into `style={color: 'red', width: "12.5%, height: 8}`?

This is all the React code I need to write to generate the Progress bar using the ant design library:

```
import { Progress } from 'antd';

<Progress
    percent={percentVotes}
    showInfo={false}
    status="active"
/>
```

I've also tried importing CSS and added an "ant-progress-bg" CSS class with the styling I want but it didn't do anything.

In my `Matches.css` file I have:

```
.ant-progress-bg {
    color: red;
}
```

which I import into my `Matches.js` file with `import './Matches.css';`

Comment: Can you share the react code you have that produces the Progress tag? If the "ant-progress-bg" is hidden from your react code, then you will have to import css and add an "ant-progress-bg" css class, with the styling you want.

Comment: I tried importing CSS and added an "ant-progress-bg" CSS class with the styling I want but it didn't do anything.

Comment: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/progress/progress.tsx#L26

Comment: The documentation covers this particular case. http://ant.design/components/progress/

Comment: @KevinB thanks but I was using `red` as an example. I actually need the color to be able to change to any color.

Comment: right. they color it based on the status. Can you not color it the same way with css that overrides theirs?

Comment: I can't add JSX and override their CSS. I'm asking how can I override theirs?

Comment: With a stylesheet. Or, make your own Progress component.

Comment: You can [look directly at the source](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/progress/progress.tsx#L95), it doesn't provide you with a way of directly altering that style attribute. To do so, you'd need to implement the component yourself with modifications that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo https://codesandbox.io/s/k0m0nl1my3

If you want to change progress bar color for all places then override this class

```
.ant-progress-bg {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

And if you want to change color only for this specific progress bar, add some extra class like

```
.my-progress-bar .ant-progress-bg {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

If you are using `less` for your custom styles, it's even simpler

```
.my-progress-bar {
  .ant-progress-bg {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}   

<Progress
  percent={percentVotes}
  showInfo={false}
  status="active"
  className="my-progress-bar"
/>
```

Comment: @QLiu Then you need to add `!important`. I updated answer

Comment: @QLiu I've created a demo here and it's working https://codesandbox.io/s/k0m0nl1my3

Comment: If still you have problem the I guess you have imported style files in wrong order. import your custom styles after Ant Design css

Comment: @QLiu Welcome .. Glad to help